# GraphQLError: Expected type Int, found Int

Tags: apollo-server

I have encountered a new type of nonsensical errors (`Expected type Int, found Int`) when running queries with input parameters (not just Ints). They seem to have appeared since early June (when I upgraded to `graphql@14.3.1`?)

Our setting is a bit different since we are stitching a remote schema to a local one (overlapping types when they exist or adding them when they are not).

Anyone has seen this type of errors and knows how to correct it?

I have traced the problem to the parseLiteral method of the scalar.js file. In the present case, ast.kind equals `EnumValue` while its value is `IntValue`

```js
var GraphQLInt = new _definition.GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Int',
  description: '...',
  serialize: serializeInt,
  parseValue: coerceInt,
  parseLiteral: function parseLiteral(ast) {
    if (ast.kind === _kinds.Kind.INT) {
      var num = parseInt(ast.value, 10);

      if (num <= MAX_INT && num >= MIN_INT) {
        return num;
      }
    }

    return undefined;
  }
});
```

It seems as if the parser arbitrarily converts a value of `10` to an `EnumValue` (of type `Int`), rather than `IntValue`.

Here is a typical query

```
combinedStatus(status: "bad", start:10, end:20) {
        status
        timestamp
      }
```

I get the following error: `GraphQLError: Expected type Int, found Int.` at isValidScalar ./node_modules/graphql/validation/rules/ValuesOfCorrectType.js:180:27

the same query with variables will return the expected result and no error:

```
combinedStatus(status: "bad", start:$start, end:$end) {
        status
        timestamp
      }
```

The schema is:

```
type CdsHealthCheckLocal implements CdsHealthCheckInterface {
    status: String!
    combinedStatus(status: String, start: Int, end: Int): CdsHealthCheck
}
```

and the corresponding resolver is:

```
async (parent, { status, start, end }, context) => { 
        return {
        status: `not sure if I am feeling ${status} (${start}, ${end})`
    }}
```

Comment: Works [just fine for me](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-56909388-5y8ob) using 14.3.1. Can you provide a reproducible example? Are you utilizing custom scalars or doing anything else funky that might be causing some unexpected issues? An example, a repo link or, at the very least, your ApolloServer config (including the typeDefs and resolvers and any other relevant bits) would be necessary to diagnose this further.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your reply, that's helpful. This is a plain vanilla sample that we use to test our engine, I guess the only thing I can think of is that we stitch a remote schema with this type, so that's probably the origin of the problem. I tested it without stitching it to a remote and it works.

Comment: Schema stitching is, in my experience, notoriously buggy, so I think it's likely that's where the issue is, but it's hard to know without seeing all the code. Please consider providing a simple reproducible example in the form of a repo or a sandbox.

Comment: Yes, I agree, we've had to deal with a number of corner cases (e.g. __typename). It's difficult to provide a fully reproducible environment, our GraphQL platform is custom built on top Apollo Server. I'll investigate further.